# How to grab records that have NULL or certain character

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have TWO column that contains NULL values and character "//" and valid values on both. I want to select all the rows that have NULL OR the character "//" in the first column and valid character in the second column. Is there a way to do this? I keep getting an error when I run this:

Does not work:

```
select COLUMN1 IS NULL OR LIKE '%//%' AND COLUMN2 NOT LIKE '%//%' 
    from TABLE
```

Works:

```
select COLUMN1 LIKE '%//N%' AND COLUMN2 NOT LIKE '%//%' 
from TABLE
```

How can I make the first statement work? To check for columns that have "//" OR has NULL values in the first column?

Comment: `(COLUMN1 IS NULL OR COLUMN1 LIKE '%//%')`

Comment: Hi there! I tried this as well, but it didn't work. I get an error that says  "line 1 at position 61 unexpected ''%//%'' )

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, you need to use parenthesis around your junction and disjunction (or, and) operators:

```
create or replace temp table foo (COLUMN1 string, COLUMN2 string);

insert into foo (COLUMN1, COLUMN2) values ('//',null), ('okay', null), ('okay', 'okay'), (null, 'okay'), ('//', 'okay');

select * from foo where 
(COLUMN1 = '//' or COLUMN1 is null) and (COLUMN2 <> '//' and COLUMN2 is not null)
```

As I understand the requirement, this will only select the final two rows that have // or NULL for the first column and valid values for the second column.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use UNION to achieve the same result.

```
select COLUMN1 LIKE '%//N%' AND COLUMN2 NOT LIKE '%//%' 
from TABLE
union
select COLUMN1 IS NULL AND COLUMN2 NOT LIKE '%//%' 
from TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
create or replace table test_1 as
(SELECT '1' as fld1, NULL as fld2 UNION ALL
SELECT '//' as fld1, NULL as fld2 UNION ALL
SELECT '21' as fld1, '5444' as fld2 UNION ALL
SELECT '//' as fld1 , '25' as fld2 UNION ALL
SELECT NULL as fld1, '//' as fld2  UNION ALL
SELECT '4500' as fld1 , '23' as fld2 UNION ALL
SELECT NULL as fld1 , '12' as fld2 );

--I want to select all the rows that have NULL OR the character "//" in the first column 
--and valid character in the second column.
select * from test_1 WHERE  (fld1 is NULL  and  (fld2 <> '//' and  fld2 is not null ))
OR (fld1 = '//'  and  (fld2 <> '//' and  fld2 is not null ));
```

Comment: fyi, you can user VALUES to write your data in a much simpler form: `SELECT * FROM VALUES ('1', null), ('//', NULL), ('21', '5444'), ('//', '25'), ('21', '5444'), (NULL, '//'), ('4500', '23'), (NULL, '12') v(fld1, fld2);`